# Ruby Method Call Made to Wrong (Top Level Module) Class

Tags: ruby, module, minitest

I am having a very strange problem regarding method dispatch to the wrong class using Minitest.

I am helping maintain the dnsruby library (https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby), and we have a particular test that intermittently fails (https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/blob/master/test/tc_resolv.rb#L56).

By setting a breakpoint in pry, I discovered that when it fails it is using the `getname` method on the internal Ruby `Resolv` class rather than the `Dnsruby::Resolv` class specified in the code. Both `::Resolv` and `Dnsruby::Resolv` seem to point to the Ruby internal `Resolv` class:

`[1] pry(#<TestResolv>)> ::Resolv.object_id
=> 70320518250220
[2] pry(#<TestResolv>)> Dnsruby::Resolv.object_id
=> 70320518250220`

The error does not occur when the test is run on its own (`ruby test/tc_resolv.rb`). When combined with other tests (using `ruby test/ts_online.rb` and modifying its list of test files that are run), it often fails but sometimes not. The only factor I have found that seems to be correlated with the failure is the amount of test code that is run; the more tests are run, the more likely it is to fail.

When the test succeeds, `::Resolv` is not even defined:

`[1] pry(#<TestResolv>)> ::Resolv.object_id
NameError: uninitialized constant Resolv`

I searched our codebase for `require 'resolv'` but did not find it.  Perhaps another library we're using is requiring it.  Even so, though, shouldn't the `Dnsruby::` in `Dnsruby::Resolv` specify our customized `Resolv` class?

How can we fix this?

Comment: i'd assume once you found out who requires resolv, it's easier to spot what is going on there. have you tried raising an error in resolv.rb so you can see where it's required?

Comment: Interesting idea.  I did that and found a test file that was requiring it.  However, when I tested only that file and the test file in question, the error did not occur; ::Resolv and Dnsruby::Resolv were both available but pointed to the correct (i.e. different) classes, and the tests passed. So the problem is not that 'resolv' is being required, it's that somehow Dnsruby::Resolv is being overwritten to point to ::Resolv in _some_ cases.

Comment: you could use `TracePoint` or `set_trace_func` to check if it get's overridden by some class.

Comment: i've just briefly looked into the github issue. could it be, that the issue is actually with celluloid? two concurrent instances, or not properly shutdown or something like that? there are two `Celluloid.boot` but no `Celluloid.shutdown` calls in the test-suite.

Comment: @phoet Thanks for your suggestions. I've opened a new Github issue about the Celluloid issue you discovered, at https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/issues/122.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing an `include Dnsruby` in the top level that should not have been there. (Thanks to Ruby community member https://github.com/matt-glover for spotting this!)

More detail is at the Github issue at https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/issues/112, and the fix is in the pull request at https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/pull/121/files.

One thing that confuses me...I would have expected that include to result in the Dnsruby::Resolv class being pulled into the top level, but it seems that the reverse happened.